# browser caching on google page speed insights. how is google treating private cache-control?

Tags: browser-cache, cache-control, pagespeed, image-caching

I have been trying to optimise page speed and particularly the way images are served and cached on this specific page:
[www.modemio.de/damen-mokassins](https://www.modemio.de/damen-mokassins)

here is the outcome:
[image: screenshot Google PageSpeed]

PageSpeed tool says the specific image is being cached only for 15 minutes.
If I go on the page itself and explore the header response for the specific image I see:

> cache-control: private, no-transform, max-age=2592000

[image: Chrome Dev Tool]

Quote:

> Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.

this is exactly what´s happening on my browser but I don´t understand why the PageSpeed tool sees only 15 minute caching.
Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Same issue here. I changed `cache-control` on nginx, I could see it when testing from my own browser, but PSI took a few days to show the new value  :-/  very annoying I never knew why it took so long. No CDN or anything else in the middle.